# A question about the decoupling of Dirac equation in 1+1 dimension

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

It is said that in 1+1 dimension, if we take $\gamma^0=i\sigma^2$ and $\gamma^1=\sigma^1$, then the two components of dirac spinor $\psi_L$(upper component) and $\psi_R$(lower component) decouple in the Dirac equation $(i\gamma^u\partial_u-m)\psi=0$ But, the Pauli matrices $\sigma^1$ and $\sigma^2$ are off-diagonal matrices. So the components of the spinor $\psi$ clearly mixes together in the equation. So what does it mean by the components decouple?

Also I think  that it is wrong to choose $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^1$ like above. In order to satisfy the Clifford algebra, I think it must be that $\gamma^0=\sigma^2$ and $\gamma^1=i\sigma^1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a fine basis, but there is no decoupling like you say. It's $\sigma^3$ whose eigenvalues distinguish the left and right movers in this basis, and while $\sigma^3$ commutes with $m$ it anticommutes with $ \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$, so the evolution mixes them. If the mass was zero, they really would decouple, because you could multiply the equation by $\gamma^0$ and then the whole thing would commute with $\sigma^3$.

Comment: You mean that $i\sigma^2$ and $\sigma^1$ are fine basis? But they do not satisfy $\{\gamma^u, \gamma^v\}=-2\eta^{uv}$ where $\eta^{uv}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$

Comment: They anticommute, and $(i \sigma_2)^2 = -1$ and $\sigma_1^2 = 1$. Looks like Cl(1,1) to me! This is the 1+1D Majorana basis.